# Function is not running after DOM ready Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my Javascript code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    thetitle();
    document.getElementById("title").onkeyup = function(){
        thetitle();
    }
    function thetitle(){
        var titlelength = 482;
        var the_title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        document.getElementById('ruler_title').innerHTML = the_title;
        var width = document.getElementById('ruler_title').offsetWidth;
        var pixels = titlelength - width;
        document.getElementById('title_count').innerHTML = pixels;
        if(pixels > 0){
            document.getElementById('title_count').classList.add("good");
            document.getElementById('title_count').classList.remove("bad");
        }else{
            document.getElementById('title_count').classList.add("bad");
            document.getElementById('title_count').classList.remove("good");
        }
    }
});

<table width="100%">
    <tr><td width="100px" valign="top"><label for="title">Titel</label></td><td valign="top"><div id="ruler_title" style="width:50px; height:1px;display:block;"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100px" valign="top"><div class="counter good" id="title_count"></div></td><td valign="top"><input id="title" name="title" class="s__input" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

If the DOM is loaded the function thetitle(); does noting. But with the keyup the function thetitle(); is running. Who can help me with this?

Comment: any error in the console? How do you know `thetitle` does not run?

Comment: `document.getElementById("title").value` is probably `''` when the page loads, unless your Browser stores those values for another page load.

Comment: There no errors in the console. If the function thetitle is running the pixels has changing and this is not happening. Only if the keyup the function is running

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue with this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        thetitle();
        inputtitle.onkeyup = function(){
            thetitle();
        }
    });
});
```

The window load function is the answer.

Comment: Why you put the load event inside DOMContentLoad?

Comment: You should use window.onLoad = function () {...}

Answer (score 0):

As @connexo said in the comments. There is no need to move the function `theTitle` to outside the event listner, unless you gona need to call it outside of the event scope.

As you said in the comments, the function is been called, but `document.getElementById('ruler_title').offsetWidth` is undefined. It heppens because on `DOMContentLoad` `offsetWidth` is not ready yet.

On `DOMContentLoad` the browser fully loaded HTML, and the DOM tree is built, **but external resources like pictures  and stylesheets may be not yet loaded.**

On `load` not only HTML is loaded, **but also all the external resources: images, styles etc.**

Be sure that `ruler_title` is present and loaded before you call `theTitle()` function.

This is an example that how you can do it. I move `thetitle` function outside of the event just to make the code more clear for future readers.

```
function thetitle() {
    var titlelength = 482;
    var the_title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    document.getElementById('ruler_title').innerHTML = the_title;
    var width = document.getElementById('ruler_title').offsetWidth;
    var pixels = titlelength - width;
    document.getElementById('title_count').innerHTML = pixels;
    if(pixels > 0){
        document.getElementById('title_count').classList.add("good");
        document.getElementById('title_count').classList.remove("bad");
    }else{
        document.getElementById('title_count').classList.add("bad");
        document.getElementById('title_count').classList.remove("good");
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    thetitle();
    document.getElementById("title").onkeyup = function() {
        thetitle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked some code and this var is not set var width = document.getElementById('ruler_title').offsetWidth;

Comment: Are you sure that you have an HTML element with id="ruler_title"? Can you share your html?

Comment: Yes the element is set. But I think the offsetWidth is not working on dom ready it response 0.

Comment: What kind of element is ruler_title? Is it an image, or anything external. If so it will not be rendered on DOMContentLoad. Will be a lot easier to help you if you share your html code too.

Comment: You may want to read about **function/variable hoisting**. No need to declare a function before calling it as long as it's declared in the same block context.

Comment: Thanks @connexo i''ll read about soon. If you want to make any changes on my answer, be my guest.

Comment: Thanks @connexao. I found a great doc about hoisting and already fix my error on this answer. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp